# How to split a string with negative numbers using ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, xml

I'm having trouble loading my level. I'm using Ogmo to create my level then I import it. I have no problem converting 0's and 1's into an Array, but I can't figure out how to do the same for -1's. It separates the "-" and the "1". Any help would be great. I've posted my code and the XML files below
EDIT: Uploaded new code.

```
levelXML = new XML(e.target.data);
        playerX = int(levelXML.Entities.Player.@x);
        playerY = int(levelXML.Entities.Player.@y);
        levelGrid = levelXML.Grid;
        levelGrid = levelGrid.split("\n").join("");
        levelTiles = levelXML.Tiles;
        levelTiles = levelTiles.split("\n").join("")
        tileArray = levelTiles.split(",")
        gridArray = levelGrid.split("");
        for(i = 0; i <= 34; i++)
        {
            levelArray[i] = new Array();
            for(j = 0; j <= 34; j++)
            {


                if(tileArray[j*35 + i] == 0)
                {
                    gridArray[j*35+i] = -1;

                }
                var currentSymbol = gridArray[j*35+i];
                levelArray[i][j] = currentSymbol;
                if(gridArray[j*35 + i] == 1)
                {
                    wall = new Wall;
                    addChild(wall);
                    wall.x = i*20 + 10;
                    wall.y = j*20 + 10;
                }
                else if(gridArray[j*35 + i] == -1)
                {
                    pellet = new Pellet;
                    addChild(pellet);
                    pellet.x = i*20 + 10;
                    pellet.y = j*20 + 10;
                }

            }
        }
```

I know the code is very dirty, but I needed a quick fix.

Grid exportMode="Bitstring">
11111111111111111111111111111111111
10000000000000000011000000000000001
10000000000000000011000000000000001
10011111001111110011001111110011001
10011111001111110011001111110011001
10011111001111110011001111110011001
10000000000000000000000000000000001
10000000000000000000000000000000001
10011111001100111111100110011111001
10011111001100000100000110011111001
10000000001100000100000110000000001
10000000001111100100111110000000001
11111111001111100100111110011111111
00000001001111100100111110010000000
00000001001100000000000110010000000
11111111001100000000000110011111111
00000000000000111111100000000000000
00000000000000100000100000000000000
11111111001100100000100110011111111
00000001001100111111100110010000000
00000001001100000000000110010000000
11111111001100111111100110011111111
10000000000000000100000000000000001
10000000000000000100000000000000001
10011111001111100100111110011111001
10000011000000000000000000011000001
10000011000000000000000000011000001
11110011001100111111100110011001111
11110011001100111111100110011001111
10000000001100000100000110000000001
10000000001100000100000110000000001
10011111111111100100111111111111001
10000000000000000000000000000000001
10000000000000000000000000000000001
11111111111111111111111111111111111

Tiles tileset="Tiles" exportMode="CSV"-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1
-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of the zeroes and ones, you have to split with `""`, but in case of the tile-numbers this doesn't work as it would create an array entry for `-` and `1` when the value should be `-1`. But luckily you have a delimiter `,` which you can use.

So instead of

```
levelTiles = levelTiles.split("\n").join("");
levelTiles = levelTiles.split(",").join("");
tileArray = levelTiles.split("");
```

Use:

```
levelTiles = levelTiles.split("\n").join(",");
tileArray = levelTiles.split(",");
```

A cleaner way to split (which also removes unnecessary white-space) could be done with a regular expression:

```
tileArray = levelTiles.replace(/\n\r?/g,",").split(/\s*,\s*/);
```

To split the Bitstring and get rid of the white-space I suggest you use this instead:

```
bitArray = bitString.replace(/\s+/g, "").split("");
```

Comment: Cool, it worked. The problem now is that the tileArray is shorter than the gridArray by one row which messes up the placement of the pellets. Ill upload the new code.

Comment: @inzombiak are you sure your exported values align (eg. same number of entries in both)? What's with the white-space in the Bitstring? This will convert to a character!

Comment: yeah, it looks weird here, but the lines appear one after another in the actual XML file. Ive checked the heights of both and theryre the same in the XML

Comment: Just to be sure, I'd split the Bitstring with the following line: `bitField = bitString.replace(/\s+/g, "").split("");`. Again, this will filter out any unnecessary whitespace

Comment: The bitstring is fine. It's supposed to be 35x35 and the length is 1225. The tiles are just short 1 row.

Comment: @inzombiak You're right. I overlooked that line-breaks actually are a delimiter and there's no `,` there. So I updated the regex method to first convert all line-breaks to `,`, then do the split. That actually gives me 1225 also.

Comment: THANK YOU! finally I can go home. Thank you very very much.